# Android - Share file without saving on external storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent, android-file

I would like to share a text content via intent, but sometimes the string is too big, so I've decided to share it as a file. I tried not to save this file on the External Storage so I don't need to mess with Storage Permissions, so I tried creating it on the cache directory and sharing it. I am inside a fragment and I've tried the following:

```kotlin
 private fun generateNoteOnSD(fileName: String, content: String) {
     try {
         val root = File(requireActivity().cacheDir.path)
         val file = File(root, fileName)
         val writer = FileWriter(file)
         writer.append(content)
         writer.flush()
         writer.close()

         val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
         intent.type = "text/plain"
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file.toURI())
         intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
         startActivity(intent)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
         e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

But it's not working. It opens the app I choose, but the file is not there.
Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The other app has no permission to access that content because it' saved on the cache directory of your app. You also may have taken some steps to block `FileUriExposedException`, because the technique that you are using (`toUri()` on `File`) has been all but banned for seven years.

Please, use `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()` to share your content, rather than trying to use `toUri()` on `File`. `FileProvider` is covered in:

- The documentation (see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file))
- [This section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack), and
- [This section](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore/pages/chap-t30-002.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore)

...among other resources.

Comment: I'll try to create something  based on this @CommonsWare, but if you know how to and can provide a code snipet, it would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you will have to do is to use a `FileProvider`. To do so, you will have to set it up in your android manifest inside the `application` tag:

```xml
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Notice that it requires you to create a xml file to define which files you will be providing. All you have to do is to create an xml file called `provider_paths.xml` (in my case) inside `res/xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="shared_data.txt"
        path="/" />
</paths>
```

Notice that I've used the `<cache-path>` tag. It means it will provide files within the chace directory. You could also use `<files-path>` and `<external-path>`, but since I want the file to be only in the memory of my app, I used `<cache-path>`. You can [learn more about it here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing?hl=pt-br#DefineMetaData).

Then, you can share your files using the code below (notice that I've created some extension functions to make it cleaner):

```kotlin
private const val FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider"
private const val FILE_PROVIDER_NAME = "shared_data.txt"

fun File.clearText() {
    PrintWriter(this).also {
        it.print("")
        it.close()
    }
}

fun File.updateText(content: String) {
    clearText()
    appendText(content)
}

fun Fragment.shareFile(content: String) {
    val application = requireActivity().application
    val file = File(application.cacheDir, FILE_PROVIDER_NAME)
    file.updateText(content)

    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(), FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, file)

    Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = "*/*"
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
    }.also { intent ->
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

The, all you have to do is to call the `shareFile()` function, passing the content you'd like to share:

```kotlin
shareFile("Hello world")
```

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you so much! I did it with this code. Any idea if I can improve it?

Comment: `name="shared_data.txt"` is a little strange -- that name really represents the shared directory. Also, your `type` should be the actual type of the content, not `*/*`. You are supplying the content, so you need to tell other apps what that content is. I am a bit nervous about `clearText()` and `updateText()`, but if you have enough unit tests to confirm they are reliable, .

Comment: "Your type should be the actual type of the content" what should I use for a text file?

Comment: `text/plain` if it is plain text. If the text is in some specific format (JSON, XML, etc.), use the MIME type for that format.

Comment: "name="shared_data.txt" is a little strange -- that name really represents the shared directory. " I'd like my app to be able to share only one file that is in the root directory called `shared_data.txt`, that's why I used `name="shared_data.txt"`. In that case, what should I do them?

Comment: `name` does not control what you share. If you only want to share `shared_data.txt`, be sure to only use that file with `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`.